# Sitecore disableWebEdit - html fails validation

Tags: html, sitecore

Working with sitecore cms, we are finding that wherever we have instances of 'disableWebEdit' added by sitecore, the resulting html is considered invalid by SiteImprove and W3C Validator.

```
    Error: Attribute disablewebedit not allowed on element a at this point.
    From line 329, column 33; to line 329, column 103
    <li><a href="https://xxxx.xxxx-uk.org/disclaimer" DisableWebEdit="True">Discla
```

As a front end developer, my first thought is to use data-disablewebedit, but the Sitecore devs on the team tell me that refactoring the sitecore process for this is likely to be a non-starter.

Is it realistic to implement the data- tag approach, or is there a more efficient way of using the disbalewebedit tag that will validate successfully?

many thanks.

Comment: Sitecore does not add this to the frontend elements, not for the website running in normal mode. It may well add them for specific fields in preview and/or edit mode in the Experience Editor... where are you running the validator from?

Comment: thanks @jammykam  - the validator is running on the live version of the site; from your comment it sounds like the tag should not be displayed in live - is this the case?  is there a setting to prevent this from happening?